# jQuery UI and loading data into a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery UI to create a tab, and I want to the contents of my php file to be entered into this tab. I start by creating a tab, and then selecting it.

```
function createTab2() {
       //create a tab
       $("#tabs").tabs("add","#tabs-2","Second Tab");
       $("#tabs-2").css("display","block");   
       $('#tabs').tabs('select', "#tabs-2");        
       $.get('tab2.php', function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);
            alert('Load was performed.');
        });
}
```

I tried using the JQuery `.get` function to return the data and it works fine as an alert appears. However, the contents are not entered into the tab - I just see them listed in my Javascript console.

How can I make the contents of the php file appear in this tab?

Comment: When you say contents do you mean raw data or data formatted in html ?

Comment: in jqueryui.com, there is a demo to load content via ajax. check it out http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

Comment: Do you only have one .result div?

Comment: @DG3 Nice - I missed that. Do you know how I combine that with the creation of a tab? I can see how I use it in the loading of an existing tab. There are no divs within the tab after I create it (another problem that I did not notice).

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation.

Comment: Is it necessary to do something like this `$('#tabs-2').id('tabs-2');` for the css to be applied to this new tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your markup for tab 2 you need add an href to the source html.

```
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
     <li><a ><span>Content 1</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="tab2.php"><span id="tabs-2">Content 2</span></a></li>
     <li><a ><span>Content 3</span></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

or you can try load the tab directly.

```
$("#tabs-2").load('tab2.php');
```

[source](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Comment: wow! `$("#tabs-2").load('tab2.php');` works. Unfortunately it does not seem to pick up on the css styles.

Comment: it will only pick up styles that are included in the calling page.

Comment: The styles are picked up if I have a static page. If I replace this `tab 2` with php, the styles are no longer applied.