# JQuery UI not detecting CSS styles when loading via php

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery UI to generate and load a tab when the user clicks a button using advice from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982347/jquery-ui-and-loading-data-into-a-tab) that I asked earlier. It loads the data fine, but it is not applying the CSS styles that were present when the page was static.

```
function createTab2() {
       // this will add a tab
       $("#tabs").tabs("add","#tabs-2","1: Population Density");     
       $("#tabs-2").load('tabs/tab2.php');
       $('#tabs').tabs('select', "#tabs-2");           
}
```

My original static file contained the following:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab Two</a></li>      
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1" style="height:300px;">     <!-- Start Tab 1 -->                
            <form >
                <div id="radio-b1">
                    <input type="radio" id="b1" name="type" value="1"   /><label for="b1">Radio Button 1</label>                        
                </div>
            </form>     
    </div>      <!-- End Tab 1 -->  

    <div id="tabs-2" style="height:250px;">     <!-- Start Tab 2 -->
            <form >
                <div id="radio-p1">
                    <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="pop_den_1" value="1"  /><label for="radio4">Radio Button 2</label>                            
                </div>
            </form>

    </div>      <!-- End Tab 2 -->
```

I replaced `Tab 2` with a button that called the javascript function `createTab2()` and saved the following code in `tab2.php`:

```
<div >          
        <form >
            <div id="radio-p1">
                <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="pop_den_1" value="1"  /><label for="radio4">Radio Button 2</label>                            
            </div>
        </form>             
</div>      <!-- End Tab 2 -->
```

I don't fully understand if I need to be adding properties to `#tab-2` when I create it (such as setting an `id` value, or other properties.

Comment: #tabs-2 means the styles get applied to an element with the id "tabs-2"

JQuery imitates CSS selectors so it means the same thing.

Comment: Is it necessary to re-apply a style to an object using the object name? I'm unclear why the contents of the tab are not displayed in the same way.

Comment: CSS is evergreen. JS hits the object so if it gets replaced you'll need to reapply anything applied by JS even if it has the same ID. You can apply to a style sheet with JS (making the style apply to elements it matches as they appear) but it's generally easier to just scoop HTML in and out of a container with the ID/class you want to hit.

Comment: I don't quite follow. So I can just re-apply all the styles? I would prefer this as I want all the contents of the tab to appear on demand.

Comment: If you're just doing .hide and .show, then sure. If it's multiple styles, you should tack them on to a class which you could set styles for in CSS like this: .activeTab { display:block; } Then just add/remove classes with JQuery instead of setting styles with JS/JQ.

Comment: To clarify, I want to load the contents from php on demand, and to apply or reload the style. I can manually add css to every object but that means I am not using all the useful aspects of JQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript function that you wrote wont automatically add styling to your elements. It will only use the styling that are there in the included jqueryui.css. I see you only have one style line in the tabs-2 in your static markup if this is the only style you want to apply to it you should just write a single js line to add this style.

This is the line that you have in your tab-2 style

> style="height:250px;"

to apply this style you can do it the following way

> $("#tabs-2").css("height", "250px");

do this before loading the tab or before calling the select on tabs-2

Comment: Thanks Abid - I'm starting to understand. I actually just want the `JQuery UI` css to show but it is not doing that (and it is more than one line). It is applied to `Tab 1` ok, but not `Tab 2`.